# 1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: php, apache, openssl

Recently my server vendor upgraded from php 5.6 to php 7.3. One of my application no longer trigger email notification. error as below:

Googled and tried with all the suggestion but no luck :(

PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number in /lib/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 97

code on line 97
public function startTLS()
{
return stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_stream, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
}

Comment: This is related to [this](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/commit/4c4b333c9164b74aaceb7ff9bef2d55f7a5514b8#diff-146cf1877f11165e6d2b6f3fb5586de757adf77b567fc819ce681a4c71f5307d) and [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69195). Basically, try just upgrading SwiftMailer. If that is not an option, you could try patching it from the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i manage to get working.

I have upgraded the SwiftMailer version. Still receive an error:

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`124-150-142-184.cprapid.com' did not match expected CN=`pod51021.outlook.com' in lib/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 106
```

Finally i have email to my server vendor to disabled SMTP restrictions so can send email via a third-party SMTP server (Office 365).

Then everything start working.